# Creating a mailbox for sendmail using adduser / mailboxes without system user accounts

Tags: sendmail, email-server, user-accounts

I want to create some mailboxes for Sendmail and I am going to do it with the *adduser* system utility, so every mailbox will be a user in the system. How do I restrict the privileges of these accounts to a minimum since they are only going to be used for mail.

And BTW, is there any alternative with this same MTA to have mailboxes without having to create system user accounts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **Dovecot** and **Cyrus** IMAP+POP servers support mailboxes without per every mailbox OS account.  Dovecot supports both virtual and system users. Cyrus supports virtual users.

***Note:***
If you choose Dovecot then Postfix may be easier to integrate than Sendmail. Sendmail does not support Dovecot SASL so AFAIK integrating SMTP AUTH is tricky without using LDAP centered configuration.

URL(s):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovecot_%28software%29
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrus_IMAP
- http://wiki2.dovecot.org/VirtualUsers
- http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/docs/cyrus-imapd/2.4.6/

Answer (score 1):

Set their shell to /bin/false. Let the usual privileges for normal users apply. As for **completely**  virtual users, turns out that [Artem Nosulchik](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2011/02/07/sendmail-for-virtual-users-with-procmail-spamassassin-and-dovecot/) has devised a clever scheme to do just that.

Whether the additional security (if any) outweighs the maintenance overhead (if any) I do not know - I never had a system breech occurring through mailbox only users. Note that any such scheme needs to take into account your MTA, MDA and MUA (i.e. imap/pop3 server) **unless** you just need file delivery (which sendmail can do on its own) and do not care about reading the mailboxes as different users (in other words, if you do not need a multiuser mailserver).

Comment: One should be aware that a /bin/false or /sbin/nologin shell could allow access to some other services (like FTP for example) if such services are available on that box.

Comment: Actually, for ftp that's not true - unless you put /bin/false in /etc/shells also - beside doing a slew of other actions if your ftp server is something like vsftpd, as it's wont to do these days. It could be true for other services, though - in  fact this is both one of the reasons to use system accounts or *not* to use system accounts, depending on which alternative you would rather have.